# JSON Parser No Value For Value in JSONArray

Tags: java, android, asp.net, json, web-services

I'm new to webservice and JSON, just saying. 
I use an ASP.NET web API to connect SQL Server and my android application, but when i reach the parsing point, i get an "No value for Value" error and the app crashes.

Here is the code of the query in the webservice, it returns a DataTable filled with the elements in the server

```
    public DataTable Tagmap() 
    {
        DataTable deptTable = new DataTable();
        deptTable.Columns.Add("no", typeof(String));
        deptTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));

        if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
        }

        string query = "SELECT COUNT(R_NOME), R_NOME FROM RUBRICHEUTENTI GROUP BY R_NOME";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                deptTable.Rows.Add(reader["no"], reader["name"]);
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
        dbConnection.Close();
        return deptTable;
    }
```

Here is the code of the DataTable on the android app

```
public class DeptTable {

int no;
String name;

public DeptTable(int no, String name) {
    super();
    this.no = no;
    this.name = name;
}

public DeptTable() {
    super();
    this.no=0;
    this.name = null;
}


public int getNo() {
    return no;
}
public void setNo(int no) {
    this.no = no;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

This is the Activity that calls the parsing method

```
public class DeptActivity extends Activity {

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView listv;
Context context;
ArrayList<String> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dept);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //setupActionBar();
    data = new ArrayList<String>();
    listv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_dept);
    context = this;

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    listv.setAdapter(adapter);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Attendi...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new AsyncLoadDeptDetails().execute();

}

protected class AsyncLoadDeptDetails extends
        AsyncTask<Void, JSONObject, ArrayList<DeptTable>> {
    ArrayList<DeptTable> deptTable = null;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<DeptTable> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = api.Tagmap();

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            deptTable = parser.parseDepartment(jsonObj);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //Log.d("AsyncLoadDeptDetails", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return deptTable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<DeptTable> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        {
            data.add(result.get(i).getNo() + " " + result.get(i).getName());

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(context,"Loading Completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dept, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And finally the parsing method itself, where i get the error at JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("Value"); and then cascading at OnPostExecute

```
public ArrayList<DeptTable> parseDepartment(JSONObject object)
{
    ArrayList<DeptTable> arrayList=new ArrayList<DeptTable>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("Value");
        JSONObject jsonObj=null;
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            jsonObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrayList.add(new DeptTable(jsonObj.getInt("no"), jsonObj.getString("name")));
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //Log.d("JSONParser => parseDep", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

I dunno what to change, i tried to put an optJSONArray or optInt/optString on the arrayList.add but i get a nullpointerException. I'm just a beginner in this so i don't really understand where could be the problem.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the problem your assigning null to values in this constructor:

```
public DeptTable() {
    super();
    this.no=0;
    this.name = null;
}
```

Comment: tried right now, it seems that nothing changed, i still get that error. thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query columns in DataTable Tagmap() do not match.

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(R_NOME), R_NOME FROM RUBRICHEUTENTI GROUP BY R_NOME";
```

It seems that you have invalid column names. Do you have "no" and "name" columns? If yes, then that might be the case. Try a simple query like this:

```
SELECT no,name FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Also note that "no" is integer so you may change this:

```
 DataTable deptTable = new DataTable();
    deptTable.Columns.Add("no", typeof(String));
    deptTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
```

to this:

```
 DataTable deptTable = new DataTable();
    deptTable.Columns.Add("no", typeof(int));
    deptTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
```

I hope that helps.